# Does django store instance values before changing it by default

Tags: python, django, versioning

For a model instance does Django store the model instance value by default that I could retrieve before it has been changed? Example I would like to get the status(model attribute) changed for a given date? I am able to check the attribute from LogEntry, But is there some default which stores the actual old value that can be retrieved before the status value had been changed? I am aware of versioning add ons in django.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're trying to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, django do not store original value of the instance.  To add versioning to your app use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) extension.

Answer (score 0):

As an other answer mentions, Django doesn't store old values by default. You can do this yourself by grabbing the old value and storing it to another attribute on your model on save.